# React-native-iap getAvailablePurchases() return empty array ios

Tags: react-native, app-store-connect, react-native-iap

I use auto renewal subscription with react-native-iap in my app
I need to check user has subscription on phone or not, for do this I use getAvailablePurchases()
like this

```
import * as RNIap from 'react-native-iap';

const init = await RNIap.initConnection();

    if (init) {
      await RNIap.getAvailablePurchases()
        .then((resp) => {
          const sortedAvailablePurchases = resp.sort(
            (a, b) => b.transactionDate - a.transactionDate,
          );

          const latestAvailableReceipt = sortedAvailablePurchases[0].transactionReceipt;

          RNIap.endConnection();
          return API({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/subscription/check-receipt',
            data: {
              latestAvailableReceipt,
            },
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          RNIap.endConnection();
        });
    }
```

When I try to do this on my test device with sandbox, it works, but if I try to do this in the store build, I get the response - empty array

P.S I draw up subscription and then start testing